# Dropdown menu when clicked it's not completely visible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a custom website with a simple mobile menu for now.

In the homepage, it's all ok. In the other pages, I have some modifies which compromise the operation of the menu. It remains under the content when clicked the collection dropdown menu.

I'm trying to use different third parties menu but the issue still persists.

```
<ul class="main-nav page-nav">
  <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><a href="collection.html">Collection</a></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Human</a>
        <a href="#">Dog</a>
        <a href="#">Accessories</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Social Wall</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

I  need to have the menu over the content totally visible when I pass the mouse hover collection.

Comment: In the link you provided, the menu is visible . I cant see what the issue is

Comment: Hi Carlo. It's hard to give solid advice without a little demo, but just a guess, it sounds like the drop down menu could use a greater `z-index`. Also what @VincentChinner said. That link shows the menu on top of all content when displayed.

Comment: Hii @Carlo your js added `display: none;` for home page to the `js--main-nav` but for other pages can not.

Comment: Hii @VincentChinner the issue is when you go in the collection page, you pass the mouse hover COLLECTION in the menu, and only a part of the dropdown menu is visible

Comment: Maybe you have a cached version of the stylesheet in your browser. Try viewing in another browser and see if the same problem persists. You can also clear the local data of the browser.

Comment: @VincentChinner I can't see the voice "Accessories" in the collection part

Comment: I can see it: https://imgur.com/a/NoT1tnM

Answer (score 0):

the content of .dropdown-content is limited by the height of .page-header and it would not be fixed by increasing the z-index of .dropdown-content.

So from dev tools I increased the height of .page-header from 25vh to 30vh and it shows the content of .dropdown-content, so you may want to do so

```
.page-header {
  height: 30vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `header` element has a fixed height and the `overflow` property set to `hidden`. Therefore, anything that exceeds the bounds of the element will be cropped out.

You can fix this by either:

```
header{
    overflow: hidden; /* removing this */
}
```

Or making the dropdown content fixed:

```
.dropdown-content{
    position: fixed; /* (i'd suggest this one) as you may need to have
                     no overflow on your header element */
}
```

Comment: @CarloVarchetta feel free to select this as an answer so that people will know it worked in the future :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you add your css aswell.
I am also guessing you are using a framework based on the classnames.

Add this info to your question in order to get an efficient response.